# CQ5/AEM list not showing a childpage when the page's hideInNav property set to true

Tags: aem

CQ5 list component built using childpages doesn't show pages as list items, whose `hideInNav=true`. Is this as expected?If yes, how to overcome this issue?Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is the expected behaviour. This flag marks the pages as hidden, so they aren't shown in the navigation and also in a list. You would have to implement the list by yourself by using `Page.listChildren()` without the `new PageFilter()` from the root `Page`.
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html